# Function JavaScript : on Menu CSS HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have problems with my menu. Currently, it's only working on the submenu dropdown.

How to enable it on the main menu too?

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
  if (target.parentElement.className.indexOf('has-submenu') > -1) {
    e.target.classList.toggle('open');
  }
}, false);
```

```css
#menu {
  background: #343434;
  color: #eee;
  height: 35px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #eeeded
}

#menu ul,
#menu li {
  margin: 0 0;
  padding: 0 0;
  list-style: none
}

#menu ul {
  height: 35px
}

#menu li {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  font: bold 12px Arial;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
  border-right: 1px solid #444;
  border-left: 1px solid #111;
  text-transform: uppercase
}

#menu li:first-child {
  border-left: none
}

#menu a {
  display: block;
  line-height: 35px;
  padding: 0 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #eee;
}

#menu li:hover > a,
#menu li a:hover {
  background: #111
}

#menu input {
  display: none;
  margin: 0 0;
  padding: 0 0;
  width: 80px;
  height: 35px;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer
}

#menu label {
  font: bold 30px Arial;
  display: none;
  width: 35px;
  height: 36px;
  line-height: 36px;
  text-align: center
}

#menu label span {
  font-size: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 35px
}

#menu ul.menus {
  height: auto;
  width: 180px;
  background: #111;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  display: none;
  border: 0;
}

#menu ul.menus li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  font: 12px Arial;
  text-transform: none;
}

#menu li:hover ul.menus {
  display: block
}

#menu a.home {
  background: #c00;
}

#menu a.prett {
  padding: 0 27px 0 14px
}

#menu a.prett::after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-width: 6px 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #eee transparent transparent transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 9px
}

#menu a.prett.open::after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-width: 6px 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent #eee transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 9px;
  right: 9px
}

#menu ul.menus a:hover {
  background: #333;
}

#menu ul.menus .submenu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 180px;
  background: #111;
  top: 0;
  width: 180px;
}

#menu ul.menus .submenu li {
  background: #111;
}

#menu ul.menus .has-submenu a.open ~ .submenu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul id='menu'>
    <li><a class='home' href='/'>Home</a></li>
    <li><a class='prett' href='#' title='Menu'>Menu</a>
      <ul class='menus'>
        <li class='has-submenu'><a class='prett' href='#' title='Dropdown 1'>Dropdown 1 + Sub Menu</a>
          <ul class='submenu'>
            <li><a href="#" title="Sub Menu">Sub Menu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Sub Menu">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Sub Menu">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#' title='Dropdown 2'>Dropdown 2</a></li>
        <li><a href='#' title='Dropdown 3'>Dropdown 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/thepio/pn0ym10e/2/

Comment: Enabling the menu to what?

Comment: I'm sorry aziu. On your other question I didn't realise what you wanted. I will fix it for you.

Comment: @aziu, I have updated the fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/pn0ym10e/3/  Is that what you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working example. You only need to catch click events for all the elements with class `has-submenu` and toggle classes etc accordingly.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
  if (target.parentElement && target.parentElement.className.indexOf('has-submenu') > -1) {
    e.target.parentElement.classList.toggle('open');
  }
}, false);
```

```css
#menu {
  background: #343434;
  color: #eee;
  height: 35px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #eeeded
}

#menu ul,
#menu li {
  margin: 0 0;
  padding: 0 0;
  list-style: none
}

#menu ul {
  height: 35px
}

#menu li {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  font: bold 12px Arial;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
  border-right: 1px solid #444;
  border-left: 1px solid #111;
  text-transform: uppercase
}

#menu li:first-child {
  border-left: none
}

#menu a {
  display: block;
  line-height: 35px;
  padding: 0 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #eee;
}

#menu li:hover > a,
#menu li a:hover {
  background: #111
}

#menu input {
  display: none;
  margin: 0 0;
  padding: 0 0;
  width: 80px;
  height: 35px;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer
}

#menu label {
  font: bold 30px Arial;
  display: none;
  width: 35px;
  height: 36px;
  line-height: 36px;
  text-align: center
}

#menu label span {
  font-size: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 35px
}

#menu ul.submenu {
  height: auto;
  width: 180px;
  background: #111;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  display: none;
  border: 0;
}

#menu ul.submenu li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  font: 12px Arial;
  text-transform: none;
}

#menu a.home {
  background: #c00;
}

#menu a.prett {
  padding: 0 27px 0 14px
}

#menu a.prett::after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-width: 6px 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #eee transparent transparent transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 9px
}

#menu .has-submenu.open > a.prett::after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-width: 6px 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent #eee transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 9px;
  right: 9px
}

#menu ul a:hover {
  background: #333;
}

#menu ul .submenu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 180px;
  background: #111;
  top: 0;
  width: 180px;
}

#menu ul.menus .submenu li {
  background: #111;
}

#menu li.has-submenu.open > .submenu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul id='menu'>
    <li><a class='home' href='/'>Home</a></li>
    <li class='has-submenu'><a class='prett' href='#' title='Menu'>Menu</a>
      <ul class='submenu'>
        <li class='has-submenu'><a class='prett' title='Dropdown 1'>Dropdown 1 + Sub Menu</a>
          <ul class='submenu'>
            <li><a href="#" title="Sub Menu">Sub Menu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Sub Menu">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Sub Menu">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#' title='Dropdown 2'>Dropdown 2</a></li>
        <li><a href='#' title='Dropdown 3'>Dropdown 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks Dude , you the Besttt :D